# Custom Exception for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

I have a custom exception extending `Exception`, however it does not seem to catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. But if I change the catch clause to catch `Exception` instead, it works as expected.

Shouldn't a superclass exception catch a subclass exception even though it is a `RuntimeException`?

Here is the cause of the exception:

```
int timeInMillis = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < commandMessage.length; i++)
        for (String commandValue : command.getArguments()) {
            try {
                if (commandValue.equals(commandMessage[i]))

                    // This is causing it.
                    timeInMillis =
                        Integer.parseInt(commandMessage[i + 1]);
                    else
                        throw new CommandSyntaxException(Problems.
                                SYNTAX_ERROR.getProblemDescription());
                } catch (CommandSyntaxException commandSyntaxException) {
                    System.out.println("foo");
                }

            }
```

`Problems` and `commandValue` are enums.

And here is my exception class:

```
public class CommandSyntaxException extends Exception {
    private String message;

    public CommandSyntaxException(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Is there any workaround (Besides catching `Exception`) ? **My intension is to catch all exceptions with my own exception in a single catch clause.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are extending Exception and creating CommandSyntaxException  it becomes a specific exception. And now you are trying to catch CommandSyntaxException   but that exception is not thrown instead ArrayIndexOutOfBound is thread, so it will not be caught.
If your code throws CommandSyntaxException then only it will be caught. :)

quick fix to this problem can be in three ways.
CommandSyntaxException extends RuntimeException
Or CommandSyntaxException  extends ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. 
Or your code throws CommandSyntaxException .

"My intension is to catch all exceptions with my own exception in a single catch clause" : 
You can catach all exceptions using Catch(Exception e) But catching all exception with a single catch clause is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

}
```

to you catch statements.

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` and `CommandSyntaxException` are different exception and if you want to catch them both you should either catch every exception separately or catch exception which is their common ancestor (`Exception`).

**Update**
If you now want to catch in 1 catch clause you can

1. wait for java 7 http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/05/better-exception-handling-in-java-7-multicatch-and-final-rethrow/
2. Make your CommandSyntax successor of ArrayIndexOutOfBounds